# Dual stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

I'm trying to understand [a proof](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01011311.pdf) that involves the dual of stochastic processes.

**The definition:** Let $X^x_t$ and $Y^y_t$ be two stochastic processes starting from $x$ and $y$ respectively. They are not necessarily on the same state space. $X^x_t$ and $Y^y_t$ are dual w.r.t. a function $f$ if $$ \mathbb{E}[f(X^x_t, y)] = \mathbb{E}[f(x,Y^y_t)]$$
where the first expectation is w.r.t. the law of $X^x_t$ and the second is w.r.t. the law of $Y^y_t$. Usually $f$ is taken to be $f(x,y) = 1_{x\geq y}$ so the dual definition becomes
$$ P(X^x_t, \geq y) = P(x \geq Y^y_t).$$

**Chapter 3 in Liggett's textbook** states the following properties of dual processes "illustrate in a simple way how information about one of the processes can be used to deduce properties of the other process."

- $P^0(X_t =0) = 1$ for all $t \geq 0$.
- $P^y(Y_t = 0)=0$ for all $t\geq 0$ and $Y>0$. (Here $P^y$ is the law of the process $Y_t$ given that it starts at $y$.)
- $L = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} P^x(X_t=0)$ exists and is either 0 or 1.
- If $L=1$, then $Y_t \rightarrow \infty$ in probability as $t\rightarrow \infty$ for any initial point $y\geq 0$.
- If $L=0$, then the distribution of $Y_t$ given $Y_0=0$ has a limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$. If, in addition, $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} P^X[0<X_t\leq y] = 0$ for all $y\geq 0$, then the distribution of $Y_t$ given $Y_0=y$ has a limit as $t\rightarrow \infty$ which is independent of $y$.

I get the proofs of the first two, which are based on the definition of duality. But the last three I don't understand. The book says that the last three parts "say that $X_t$ escapes to $\infty$ with positive probability for initial states other than zero iff $Y_t$ is positive recurrent.

**I just don't get the connection between $X_t$ and $Y_t$. Is there a real-world example of dual processes? Or some intuitive explanation?**

Comment: "The blog post says that the dual of a stochastic process Xt is roughly the reversed process." That's not really true, and also not what is written in the Blog. It only says, that one of the processes offen can be modelled forward, the other backward in time. That's something totally different then reversibility. In fact, typically, the nature between a process and it's dual can differ heavyly. Yet, one can use it in order to infer on properties of the other process, respectively.

Comment: @Tobsn it only states the direction that each process moves in time? In that case I'm even more unsure about the connection between the two processes. I've edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: @Tobsn the proof in https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01011311.pdf interprets the dual process as a time-reversal of the original process... even if this isn't the general interpretation, it seems to have that here? (It's in the section 2.3 "outline of the proofs".)

Comment: "this reduces the study of a Markov process on an uncountable space ({- I, 1 } z in our case) to the study of its simpler dual process which generally is a Markov chain on a countable space, e.g., a family of finite subsets of"

Comment: You should probably start with Ethier, Kurtz, Markov processes, which contains a good introduction and examples for dualities